# Multiline && combinator operator for command chaining in batch file

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-file, cmd.exe, newlines

[I see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198011/4550451) that this operator is used in windows (and might be Linux?) to chain/combine multiple commands in one line. Commands are executed one after another, as long as preceding complete successfully (exit code 0).

However, I do not understand if it can be used in batch file, where you specify commands one after another, one command per line. How do you achieve the same effect in this case? **How do you split `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3` into multiple lines**? How do you terminate

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

as soon as first command fails?

I would also like to know the name of the operator to find the answer to questions like this myself later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

can be written in multiple lines as

```
cmd1
if not errorlevel 1 cmd2
if not errorlevel 1 cmd3
```

where each command execution will depend on the result of the previous one

Answer (score 8):

In GNU/Linux I can split the command `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3` into multiple lines in (e.g. for readability) in a script file like this:

```
cmd1 &&
cmd2 &&
cmd3
```

Comment: Useful it works even from the `bash` command-line (tested from  4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2013)...

Comment: This works, no need to add the extra `' \ '`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between them is:

```
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
```

will fire each command individually and allows for the termination of the batch job if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> before one finishes.

Where as

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

will launch the commands one after the other, but, without looking at the script/in one go.

For further example,

Take the first example, if you edit the script whilst cmd1 is running and change cmd2 to cmd3, it will load cmd3 when cmd1 has finished.

On Linux, if I do `ifdown eth0` I will lose my ssh session, so, instead I do `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` to chain the commands.

If you want to do something with regards to fails, you should look at if statements and switches along with return codes and errorlevels. [Linky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827837/accessing-errorlevel-from-bash-script) .

Answer (score 0):

#### How does && work?

> However, I do not understand if it can be used in batch file, where you specify commands one after another, one command per line

The rest of this answer is for Windows batch files.

---

#### How do you split `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3` into multiple lines?

The commands can be split using `if` and `%errorlevel%`

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cmd1
if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (
  cmd2
  if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (
    cmd3
    )
  )
```

---

#### I would also like to know the name of the operator `&&`

The `&&` operator is one of two **Conditional Operators**. The other is `||`.

> `commandA && commandB`      Run `commandA`, if it succeeds then run
>   `commandB`
>
> `commandA || commandB`      Run `commandA`, if it fails then run
>   `commandB`

Source [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [%Errorlevel%](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) - Almost all applications and utilities will set an exit code when they complete/terminate.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators

Comment: The inner tests will fail unless you use delayed expansion

Comment: Good catch. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

For batch file, you need adding a ^ delimiter after each conditional operation && (or ||). For instance:

```
echo 1 && ^
echo 2 && ^
copy >null && ^
echo 4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).